# Hook up two raspberry pis with static ip adresses

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi3, static-ip-address

I want to hook up two Raspberry Pis via a network cable in order to send commands from one Pi to the other.
To do so, I want to set a static IP address on both Pis. I know I will have to edit the `dhcpcd.conf`-file.

My first approch was:

```
`interface eth0
static ip_address=169.254.250.193/24
static routers=169.254.255.255
static domain_name_servers=169.254.255.255`
```

with the ip address and router given from my ifconfig after I hook up both Pis.

However, the ifconfig does show me the interface eth0, but does not include any ip address or broadcast address.

I also went for `sudo service dhcpcd status` and it says:

`...
Jan 22 15:00:23 raspberrypi dhcpcd[376]: eth0: no IPv6 Routers available
...`

I have got 2 questions:

1. Do you think it is even neccessary to give both pis a static address if I'm only working on a direct ethernet network cable connection? The Pis will both boot up and should start communicate on their own in the future application.
2. If yes, how can I change the Ip address to a static one, since I'm not passing any router?

Thank you so much!

Best regards,
Tobi

Answer (score 0):

Oh wow guys, that was quick. I found a solution for that.

I know you should not touch the interfaces file anymore, but this was what did the job for me.

I used the IP address and the netmask given in `ifconfig` and the gateway from `route -n`.

I added to the interfaces file:

`auto eth0
address 169.254.255.193
netmask 255.255.0.0
gateway 0.0.0.0`

with just a difference in the address for both pis. And now everything works fine for me. After reboot, I see their static addresses.

Still, if anyone has a better solution to do this, I would be more than happy.

Thanks you all!
Tobi

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a better way to achieve this on `raspberry pi`, but wouldn't the classic approach work? It is to

- turn the NIC device `down`
- change its IP
- turn it `up` again
- optionally wrap these into a `sh` script and make it run on an init level of your choice

example (assuming debianish distro and NIC device of name `eth0`)

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down
sudo ifconfig eth0 169.254.250.193
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

I would also recommend to stop all dhclient services if present (`dhclient`, `network-manager`, etc)

Maybe more info to be found: https://askubuntu.com/q/459140